# How to adjust the table width of jspdf

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I have here a simple table which I wanted to export in pdf using jspdf. It is a 20 column table in which it has hidden column that will be also exported in pdf. I have here an example of my problem: [jsfiddle.net/riichan/1f8pbpg8/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/riichan/1f8pbpg8/5/)

This is my code which I use in exporting to pdf:

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    $("td:hidden,th:hidden","#tab_customers").show();
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#customers')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

As you can see in the output it was a mess.

**EDIT**

I have tried the code below but it is only for fixed values in the table since you need to manually adjust the column width and also only one column width is editable.

```
function demoFromHTML() {
        $("td:hidden,th:hidden","#tab_customers").show();
    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
     pdf.cellInitialize();
    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    $.each( $('#tab_customers tr'), function (i, row){
        $.each( $(row).find("td, th"), function(j, cell){
             var txt = $(cell).text().trim().split(" ").join("\n") || " ";
             var width = (j==0) ? 70 : 45; //make with column smaller
             //var height = (i==0) ? 40 : 30;
             pdf.cell(10, 50, width, 50, txt, i);
        });
    });
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');

}
```

This is the sample: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/riichan/4wqs6kfu/7/)

Comment: You wanted to just???

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mooadpet/

Comment: @SameerShemna Hi. Thank you for your time answering my question but as I have said `it is only for fixed values`. The thing is I'm getting my values from a database and if the value is long then it will overlap with the next column. Just like the one in example.